# Multiprocess conditional/named Lock

Tags: python, locking, mutex

In a multiprocess program I want to lock certain function based on arguments e.g.

```
def calculate(spreadsheet):
    _do_calc(spreadsheet)
```

Now what I want to do is based on spreadsheet, lock the function so that multiple spreadsheets can be worked on concurrently but two calls on same spreadsheet will lock e.g.

```
def calculate(spreadsheet):
    with Lock(spreadsheet.id):
      _do_calc(spreadsheet)
```

Is it possible with multiprocessing.Lock , if not what are the alternatives? I am thinking of using fcntl based file locking.

**Edit**:
Above was a very simplified version of my problem, basically I am not using multiprocessing module, I have N number of different scripts which work on some data and sometimes same data which I wanted to avoid, so wanted someway to synchronize them at some points, e.g. all of them may import a module mylock and use mylock.lock  to synchronize

```
import mylock

def calculate(spreadsheet):
    with mylock.lock(spreadsheet.id):
      _do_calc(spreadsheet)
```

What are the various ways i can write mylock.lock, currently I just create a file with name spreadsheet.id and delete it when lock releases.

Comment: With [ilock](https://github.com/symonsoft/ilock) you can use named system-wide locks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might be able to improve on simple file opening with [this recipe](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/519626-simple-file-based-mutex-for-very-basic-ipc/), which I have tested on Linux and Windows.

Comment: I am actually using fcntl.lockf which works pretty well, but wanted to see if there are any better solutions

Answer (score 2):

Why not give each spreadsheet a `Lock` as an instance attribute?

```
class Spreadsheet(...):
    def __init__(self, ...):
        self.lock = multiprocessing.Lock()

    ...
```

and then

```
def calculate(spreadsheet):
    with spreadsheet.lock:
        ...
```

Comment: In some cases the instance is created after the processes branch - but it still has some attribute to identify as the same one, e.g. path or some name.